# Illegal invocation on spy object

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a `Spy` object which will monitor how many times a method on another object gets called. I can get the monitoring working by wrapping the target's method in my `Spy`, but when I try to invoke the target's method, I get an `Illegal invocation` error, and I'm unsure why.

```
function Spy(target, method) {
    var counter = 0;
    var oldFunc = target[method];
    target[method] = function(args){
        return (function(){
            counter++;
            oldFunc(args); //ILLEGAL
        })();
    }
    return { count : counter }
}
var spy = Spy(console, 'error');
console.error('foo', 'bar');
console.error('foobar');
console.log(spy.count);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s505eemb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problems with your function invocation are:

- you're not passing all arguments
- you're not passing the expected `this` value
- you're not returning the result value

Use the [`apply` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to fix this.
Btw, that IEFE is useless, and you're not updating the `.count` property, but only the local `counter` variable.

```
function Spy(target, method) {
    var counter = 0;
    var oldFunc = target[method];
    target[method] = function() {
        counter++;
        return oldFunc.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    return { get count() { return counter; } }
}
```

([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s505eemb/2/))

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Not if the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is used

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for the explanation. I'm unclear as to why you supplied `this` to `apply()`, I was surprised to see `this` resolving to the `target`.

Comment: first parameter is the object on which the oldFunc method will be invoked i.e. "this" inside oldFunc will refer to this object. Assuming 'method' is invoked on target by caller, the function inside Spy will have 'this' referring to 'target'.